# How to add dates not in a data frame with a count of 0?

Tags: r

I have data for some dates with counts; the other dates, where the event I'm counting didn't occur, do not appear in this data set. In order to do some analysis, I'd like to create a data frame that includes those missing dates but with a count of 0. Here is what some data might look like:

```
mydates <- c("2013-10-01", "2013-10-04", "2013-10-05", "2013-10-08")
mycounts <- c(2,4,3,1)
df <- data.frame(mydates,mycounts)
```

I know how to create a vector with all the dates:

```
alldates <- seq.Date(as.Date("2013-10-01"), as.Date("2013-10-08"), "days")
```

What I want to do is check whether each item in alldates exists in df$mydates; if it does, then use the corresponding count from the data frame in a new vector and if it doesn't, use 0 as the count in a new vector. But I'm not having much luck. For example, this

mycount <- ifelse(alldates %in% df$mydates, df$mycounts, 0)

gives me a vector but an inaccurate one.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Another idea: `( match(alldates, as.Date(df$mydates)) )` ; `df$mycounts[match(alldates, as.Date(df$mydates))]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mydates <- c("2013-10-01", "2013-10-04", "2013-10-05", "2013-10-08")
mycounts <- c(2,4,3,1)
df <- data.frame(mydates,mycounts)

alldates <- data.frame(
  mydates = seq.Date(as.Date("2013-10-01"), as.Date("2013-10-08"), "days")
)

merge(
  alldates,
  df,
  all = TRUE
)
```

Output -

```
      mydates mycounts
1  2013-10-01       NA
2  2013-10-01        2
3  2013-10-02       NA
4  2013-10-03       NA
5  2013-10-04       NA
6  2013-10-04        4
7  2013-10-05       NA
8  2013-10-05        3
9  2013-10-06       NA
10 2013-10-07       NA
11 2013-10-08       NA
12 2013-10-08        1
```

Comment: Thanks very much, that gets me close, I'll change the NAs to 0 and then sum by date.